# How to set logging level while running cargo test?

Tags: logging, rust, rust-cargo

I need to change the logging level while running the unit tests for a library. I am using the `cargo test` command to run the tests.

Is there any way to specify the logging level on the command line?  From the documentation of the log crate, it seems like I need to define an environment variable separately. That may not be convenient as I would like to change the logging level to debug only when a test case fails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cargo doesn't support this yet, but you are welcome to file an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/new) for it.

`RUST_LOG=debug cargo test` should work, you can set environment variables for single commands instead of setting them for the current environment.

More info on the `RUST_LOG` env variable [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/log/).

Comment: Actually this style doesn't work in Windows, since working with environment variables in Windows is slightly less straightforward.

Comment: @ShaileshKumar `SET RUST_LOG=debug; cargo test; SET RUST_LOG=`

Comment: Tried that. Have to run each command separately rather than in one line.

Comment: Issue filed https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/818

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177845/how-to-initialize-the-logger-for-integration-tests/41335165#41335165) for a quick and dirty solution.