# How to initialize the logger for integration tests?

Tags: rust

I have a crate with production code in the `src` directory and integration tests in the `tests` directory. The production code uses `log` macros.

I would like to init a global logger when running the integration tests (e.g. `env_logger::init().unwrap();`)
There are several tests and the test order is not defined, so I don't know in which test I should put the initialize command.

Is there any way I can do this nicely? Perhaps by overriding the tests `main` function?

Answer (score 46):

You can use something like this:

```
use std::sync::Once;

static INIT: Once = Once::new();

/// Setup function that is only run once, even if called multiple times.
fn setup() {
    INIT.call_once(|| {
        env_logger::init().unwrap();
    });
}
```

Then simply call `setup()` in the beginning of each test.

Originally based on [this blogpost](https://medium.com/@ericdreichert/run-code-once-in-rust-e2b75be41c39).

Comment: Could anyone provide a full example? Where this code should go?

Comment: @xliiv Just copy this code in your test file, then call `setup()` in each test. Beware, the `env_logger::init()` no longer returns a `Result`, hence the `unwrap` should be removed (see `try_init` for a `Result`).

Comment: This technique also works to initialize a `simple_logger` instance by substituting `env_logger::init().unwrap()` with `simple_logger::init_with_env().unwrap()`.

Answer (score 13):

The latest documentation has a recommendation on [Capturing logs in tests :: env_logger](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.9.1/env_logger/#capturing-logs-in-tests):

> Records logged during cargo test will not be captured by the test harness by default. The Builder::is_test method can be used in unit tests to ensure logs will be captured:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    fn init() {
        let _ = env_logger::builder().is_test(true).try_init();
    }
 
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        init();
        info!("This record will be captured by `cargo test`");
 
        assert_eq!(3, 1 + 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the documentation is attempting to show, but the `init` function is never called by anything and the `info!` line is not printed when the test either passes or fails (via `RUST_LOG=info cargo test`).

Comment: The `init` function has to be called explicitly, it's fixed in [docs for v0.6.2](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.6.2/env_logger/#capturing-logs-in-tests). Also, log printing happens only if the test fails (which i think is good).

Comment: I'm getting `panicked at 'env_logger::init should not be called after logger initialized: SetLoggerError(())',`

Comment: This looked promising but had no effect on my integration test (https://github.com/near/workspaces-rs/). Also, the latest link I think is https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.9.0/env_logger/index.html#capturing-logs-in-tests.

Answer (score 6):

For now, you can just re-initialize the logger at the top of every test and ignore the error. It's not a pretty solution but it works and is perfectly safe.

```
let _ = env_logger::try_init();

// your test code...
```

Comment: This no longer works,  you get an panic when calling init multiple times:
`panicked at 'env_logger::init should not be called after logger initialized: SetLoggerError(())`

Comment: Maybe `try_init`?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Danilo Bargen's comment, you can write it in a shorter form:

```
use std::sync::Once;

static INIT: Once = Once::new();

fn setup() {
  INIT.call_once(env_logger::init);
}
```