# logging while running `cargo test`

Tags: unit-testing, testing, logging, rust, rust-cargo

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

fn whatever() {
    info!("whatever")
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    whatever();
}
```

I want to see the log after running unit tests (`cargo test`),
how is it possible *now*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `log` crate doesn't do any logging by itself. From [the main documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/index.html):

> If no logging implementation is selected, the facade falls back to a "noop" implementation that ignores all log messages.

For your logging messages to go anywhere, you have to initialize a particular logging implementation, such as [`env_logger`](https://crates.io/crates/env_logger). However, it seems that right now, [there is no way to perform initialization before tests are run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177845/how-to-initialize-the-logger-for-integration-tests).

Comment: Isn't there any workaround? D: