# Reuse expensive runtime-generated values across async tests

Tags: testing, rust, runtime, rsa, dynamically-generated

I have a large amount of tests in my Rust code, and I require a RSA key pair for each of them. However, generating RSA key pairs is expensive and takes 3-4 seconds. I can reuse a single RSA key pair across all tests, but I'm not sure how to do that. At the moment, I'm generating an RSA key pair for each test separately.

**Update**: The tests are async tests and need to use the key pairs as `Arc`s, so `lazy_static!` won't work (returns reference)

#### What I have right now:

```rust
use rsa::{hash, PaddingScheme, PublicKey, RSAPublicKey};

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_1() {
        let (pub_key, priv_key) = new_keypair();
        // ...
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_2() {
        let (pub_key, priv_key) = new_keypair();
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    fn new_keypair() -> (RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey) {
        use rand::rngs::OsRng;
        let mut rng = OsRng;
        let bits = 2048;
        let private_key =
            RSAPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).expect("Failed to generate private key");
        let public_key = RSAPublicKey::from(&private_key);
        (public_key, private_key)
    }
}
```

#### (pseudocode for) What I need:

```rust
use rsa::{hash, PaddingScheme, PublicKey, RSAPublicKey};

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    // Pseudo-code
    #[tokio::test_main]
    async fn main() {
        let (pub_key, priv_key) = new_keypair();
        run_tests(pub_key, priv_key);
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_1(pub_key: RSAPublicKey, priv_key: RSAPrivateKey) {
        // ...
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_2(pub_key: RSAPublicKey, priv_key: RSAPrivateKey) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    fn new_keypair() -> (RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey) {
        use rand::rngs::OsRng;
        let mut rng = OsRng;
        let bits = 2048;
        let private_key =
            RSAPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).expect("Failed to generate private key");
        let public_key = RSAPublicKey::from(&private_key);
        (public_key, private_key)
    }
}
```

Comment: test are mean to be independent if you want to reuse same data, just call test_1 and test_2 inside your "main_test"

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379677/147192 answer your question? In the answer, there are multiple solutions presented and one of them uses `lazy_static` to only compute something once.

Comment: @Stargateur I don't want to lose parallel testing (or implement it myself, if possible). Additionally, I lose cargo's output / abstractions (separate output for each test, capturing output for successful tests)

Comment: You can use [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) to create a global key pair. Note however that the test harness may choose to run tests in different processes, which would create a new key pair for each process.

Comment: well you could put these test in ignore list so there are not run every time, only for final workflow, I think you should keep your tests that way.

Comment: Please do make sure your tests are not dependent on having random key pairs, I've seen problems where a smaller private exponent or a encryption / signing result without zero padding fails horribly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lazy_static` to initialize the key pair only once.
However, with this approach, you will only be able to work with shared references.
If that is not a problem for your use case, the following code should get you started.

**Edited in response to update**: The same principle also applies when dealing with other types. The following code uses `Arc` and `async` tests.

```rust
use rsa::RSAPrivateKey;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub async fn consume(key: Arc<RSAPrivateKey>) {
    // unimplemented!("")
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use lazy_static::lazy_static;
    use rsa::{RSAPrivateKey, RSAPublicKey};
    use std::sync::Arc;

    lazy_static! {
        static ref PRIV_KEY: Arc<RSAPrivateKey> = Arc::new(new_priv_key());
        static ref PUB_KEY: Arc<RSAPublicKey> = Arc::new(PRIV_KEY.to_public_key());
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_1() {
        let priv_key = PRIV_KEY.clone();

        consume(priv_key).await
    }

    fn new_priv_key() -> RSAPrivateKey {
        use rand::rngs::OsRng;
        let mut rng = OsRng;
        let bits = 2048;
        let private_key =
            RSAPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).expect("Failed to generate private key");
        private_key
    }
}
```

Based on the [documentation of `RSAPrivateKey`](https://docs.rs/rsa/0.4.0/rsa/struct.RSAPrivateKey.html#method.to_public_key), you might not even need the `RSAPublicKey`, since `RSAPrivateKey` implements the `PublicKey` trait.

Comment: I tried this out, however it won't work because I need a thread safe `Arc` (required by external crate) -- Any other way I could do this?

Comment: Where do you need the `Arc`? Inside the test? Perhaps you could update your question with a full test?

Comment: The tests are async tests (I see now that I should have specified this earlier) and need to pass `Arc`s to crate functions - Updated the question accordingly