# Add logs to cargo bench

Tags: testing, rust, benchmarking, rust-criterion

I'm using the [criterion library](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/) to benchmark some code and am in need of printing logs via the [log crate](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/). I ran the following command on this snippet of code:

```
cargo bench --bench my_benchmark

warn!("Please warn");
println!("Please print");
```

But surprisingly found that my output looked like this:

```
Please print
```

At first when I wasn't seeing logs I figured I was missing the `--nocapture` flag based on a similar question asked on SO on adding [logs to unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106554/why-doesnt-println-work-in-rust-unit-tests) and the [criterion docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/cargo/commands/cargo-bench.html#display-options). This had no effect. Neither did adding the `RUST_LOG` [parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804441/how-to-set-logging-level-while-running-cargo-test).

```
# Same output as above
cargo bench --bench my_benchmark -- --nocapture

# Same output as above
RUST_LOG=debug cargo bench --bench my_benchmark
```

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious from a crate feature or if this is possible at all. Any help would greatly improve my time to debug. Thank you!

Comment: The `log` crate doesn't actually do any logging, it just provides a common API for actual logging implementations to hook into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the logger initialization to each benchmark.

```
use log::warn; 

env_logger::builder().is_test(true).try_init().unwrap();
warn!("This prints");
```